Python 33.15 LAB: Parsing dates Zybooks Instructor note: The skills required for this lab are covered in Chapter 10. Strings
Write a program to read dates from input, one date per line. Each date's format must be as follows: March 1, 1990. Any date not following that format is incorrect and should be ignored. The input ends with -1 on a line alone. Output each correct date as: 3/1/1990.
Hint: Use string[start:end] to get a substring when parsing the string and extracting the date. Use the split() method to break the input into tokens.
Ex: If the input is:
March 1, 1990
April 2 1995
7/15/20
December 13, 2003
-1
then the output is:
3/1/1990
12/13/2003
def get_month_as_int(monthString):
if monthString == 'January':
    month_int = 1
elif monthString == 'February':
    month_int = 2
elif monthString == 'March':
    month_int = 3
elif monthString == 'April':
    month_int = 4
elif monthString == 'May':
    month_int = 5
elif monthString == 'June':
    month_int = 6
elif monthString == 'July':
    month_int = 7
elif monthString == 'August':
    month_int = 8
elif monthString == 'September':
    month_int = 9
elif monthString == 'October':
    month_int = 10
elif monthString == 'November':
    month_int = 11
elif monthString == 'December':
    month_int = 12
else:
    month_int = 0

return month_int

user_string = input()
TODO: Read dates from input, parse the dates to find the one
in the correct format, and output in m/d/yyyy format
while True:
user_string = input()
if user_string == -1:
    break
else:
    is_valid = False
    char = user_string.find(",")

    if char != -1:
        is_valid = True

    if is_valid == True:
        words = user_string.split()
        month = words[0]
        days = words[1]
        year = words[2]
        
        print(f'{month_str}/{day}/{year}')

    elif is_valid == False:
        continue

My program works with a few bugs:
I can not figure out why it keeps throwing a error on my input line except it is after the While True:
but I need to loop through multiple inputs.
Also can not figure out how to get rid of the comma in the in the day string
This is my inputs and results:
Enter program input (optional)
March 1, 1990
April 2 1995
7/15/20
December 13, 2003
-1
Program errors displayed here
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/runner/local/submission/main.py", line 35, in 
user_string = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Program output displayed here
3/1,/1990
12/13,/2003

I figured it out:

To remove the comma I wrote:
month = words[0]
days = words[1]
days = days.split(',')
day = days[0]
as far as the input error I left it as is and submitted and it passed all of the tests including the error on each test but it passed

while True:
    user_string = input()
    
    if user_string == '-1':
        break

    if "," not in user_string:
        continue
    
    user_string = user_string.split()

    month = get_month_as_int(user_string[0])    
    day = user_string[1].replace(",","")
    year = user_string[2]

    print('{}/{}/{}'.format(month,day,year))


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I updated the code in Python. Hope it is useful for you.
def get_month_as_int(monthString):
    if monthString == 'January':
        month_int = 1
    elif monthString == 'February':
        month_int = 2
    elif monthString == 'March':
        month_int = 3
    elif monthString == 'April':
        month_int = 4
    elif monthString == 'May':
        month_int = 5
    elif monthString == 'June':
        month_int = 6
    elif monthString == 'July':
        month_int = 7
    elif monthString == 'August':
        month_int = 8
    elif monthString == 'September':
        month_int = 9
    elif monthString == 'October':
        month_int = 10
    elif monthString == 'November':
        month_int = 11
    elif monthString == 'December':
        month_int = 12
    else:
        month_int = 0

    return month_int

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # March 1, 1990 April 2 1995 7/15/20 December 13, 2003 -1
    while True:
        user_string = input("Enter input: ")
    
        if int(user_string) == -1:
            break
        else:
            is_valid = False
            char = user_string.find(",")

            if char != -1:
                is_valid = True

            if is_valid == True:
                words, year = user_string.split(',')
                month, days = words.split(' ')
                
                month_str = get_month_as_int(month.strip())
                
                print(f'{month_str}/{days.strip()}/{year.strip()}')

            elif is_valid == False:
                continue

The output:
Enter input: March 1, 1990 
3/1/1990
Enter input: April 2 1995
Enter input: 7/15/20
Enter input: December 13, 2003
12/13/2003
Enter input: -1

